# Sub String in C#.net

Tags: c#, string, substring

Hi guys I have this string:

```
string myString = "152mm---Brown---0.025";
```

what I want is to take the last number "0.025" how can I do that
Please just to be more clear the number may change it is not always has the same length 
Thanks in advance,

Rasha.

Comment: You haven't clearly defined the problem. Is the string ALWAYS the same? Or is it changing, but follows the same pattern? Or something else?

Comment: Is the string always that long? Have you always the 5 last letters to take?

Comment: Yet another question with 5 answers within the first five minutes with no references to documentation, and yet the frequency of upvotes on this kind of answer is high.

Answer (score 7):

```
myString.Split(new[]{"---"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
 myString.Split(new[]{"---"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Last()
```

Comment: Nice use of LINQ!  Although you probably meant `myString.Split(new []{"---"},StringSplitOptions.None).Last();`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is completely wrong. Even if you used double quotes, there is still no matching overload for Split() that takes a single string.

Comment: @Justin Niessner which is extremely annoying.

Comment: I agree, I never understood why they didn't include a simple string separator version.  I use that all the time, but almost never do I split based on an array of either char or string.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of different ways, all depending on how the format of the string is defined.

Assuming the string is always delimited with `---` you could do:

```
string myString = "152mm---Brown---0.025";
string last = myString.Split(new string[] {"---"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf("---") + 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myString.Split(new []{"---"},StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
```

this would also work, but it's a hack:

```
myString.Split('-').Last();
```